# jQuery filter - items not re-organising (isotope)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope, masonry

I have a page that has a structure like this:

```
<div id="k2Container"> <!--sets K2 Category Layout-->
    <div class="itemList"> <!--Contains the items loaded-->
        <div id="itemListLeading"></div> <!--contains one tile that is always first-->
        <div id="itemListPrimary"></div> <!--contains the rest of the tiles-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The tile within itemListLeading has a class of 'itemContainer blue' and the tile(s) within itemListPrimary have a class of 'itemContainer red'. The filter below filters the items accordingly, but the grid isn't responsive and the tiles don't re-organise.

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All sizes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".red">Wide</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".blue">High</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".green">Small</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#k2Container');     
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.itemContainer',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: '#blank-item'
            }
        });

        $('#filters').on('click', 'a', function() {
            var selector = $(this).data('filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                layoutMode: 'masonry'
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

The masonry configuration in another location sets the container widths etc, which I'm guessing I need to call once the items have been filtered; however I'm not sure how. This can be provided upon request, I just don't want to bulk this out with too much script.

**Update**

I think I've found the problem, however I'm not sure how to amend it. When the page is loaded, the grid is fine. The styling for the tile is as follows.

```
style="position: absolute; left: 728px; top: 0px; width: 354px;"
```

Obviously the 'left: 364px' increments for each tile, as does the 'top: 0px' for each row, but when the filter is applied the styling is this (for the same tile):

```
style="position: absolute; left: 728px; top: 0px; width: 354px; transform: translate3d(354px, 0px, 0px);"
```

If I remove the '354px' from the translate 3d, the tiles realign next to each other. Any ideas as to why this is being generated?

Comment: both the divs have `id="itemListLeading"`......are you sure this is right or did you mean second div to have  `id="itemListPrimary "`

Comment: Sorry yes, error on my behalf.

Comment: edit your question making the above changes

Comment: Done. I've tried different Isotope 'layoutModes', but they just mess up the styling.

Comment: I've updated the question with a potential cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

And why you don't want create one parent element for grid, with items as childrens? Then you may do filtering with fixed first item. Add a class "item-lead" for first element, which must be fixed, and add `selector+=", .item-lead";` after `var selector = $(this).data('filter');`.

[Working example, forked on isotope default example](http://codepen.io/haemmid/pen/dYdpMm/)

Excuse me if I do not fully understand your question, but I think my method is easier than to divide the grid into two parts. ;)